# What is a "javascript generated link"?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I saw this language in a blog, but am wondering what exactly it means.

Comment: It's a link that doesn't exist on the page until it's put there by javascript. No javascript, no link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means a hyperlink (`a`) or `link` that was dynamically created and inserted into the page by JavaScript, as opposed to a link that was in the original HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine it's like this:

```
<a id="linkId" href="here" display="none">
<script>
    document.getElementById("linkId").href = "there";
    document.getElementById("linkId").display= "block";
</script>
```

Or, actually creating the node in the DOM later, like Jacob said, like this:

```
function insertcode()
{
    var code ="<a id="new_link" href="there">link text</a>"
    var myText = document.createTextNode(code);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(myText);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, first down voted answer so far. Any suggestions as to why my answer sucks? OK, I confused visibility and display.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but your code is invalid.  Your `a` in the first block isn't closed, and there is no (standard) `href` or `display` property for an `a` element.  In the second block, your `code` string is malformed, and using `createTextNode` is incorrect for generating HTML.

Comment: This is why you should run your HTML through a validator before using it, even as a Stackoverflow example...